# link uidatepicker to button and current latest time

Tags: swift

I want if “Pickup ASAP” button is clicked, then then the nearest  time ahead of the current time (of the time present in the list of UIDatePicker) should be selected and displayed, otherwise selected time should be displayed.

[image]
I tried searching stackoverflow and also tried myself but could not even get to print something in text when a date is clicked on uidatepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to connect the picker to an action like so:

```swift
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(someFunction), for: .valueChanged)
```

and in that function you can then print the newly selected date:

```swift
@objc func someFunction() {
     print(datePicker.date)
}
```

`UIDatePicker` also has a method `setDate(_ date: Date, animated: Bool)` which you can then use to figure out and set the next available date

Comment: how to link the above code to viewcontroller. I tried but could not succeed.